# SAP HANA insert into table, select from calcualtion view fails

Tags: runtime-error, hana, insert-into

System SAP HANA 1 SPS 12 : 1.00.112.16.1520578817

The following SQL fails :

```
drop table #my_new_table;

create local temporary column table #my_new_table (
    "AMPEL" varchar(5000),
    "ReportingLevel0" varchar(5000) , 
    "ReportingLevel1" varchar(255), 
    "ReportingLevel2" varchar(255), 
    "PosStatus" varchar(255), 
    "DirtyValue" double, 
    "DirtyValueT0" double,
    "FullPL" double, 
    "CashPL" double, 
    "UniqueID" varchar(255), 
    "CHECK_ID" BIGINT , 
    "NAME" varchar(255), 
    "CT" varchar(255), 
    "CT_ERGEBNIS_UNIQUE_ID" BIGINT , 
    "RUN_ID" BIGINT 
);

truncate table #my_new_table;
insert into #my_new_table (ampel, "ReportingLevel0")
select ampel, "ReportingLevel0" from (
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN "CT_ERGEBNIS_UNIQUE_ID" IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 8 END as "AMPEL", 
    "ReportingLevel0", "ReportingLevel1", "ReportingLevel2", "PosStatus", "DirtyValue", "DirtyValueT0",
    "FullPL", "CashPL", "UniqueID", "CHECK_ID", b."NAME", "CT", "CT_ERGEBNIS_UNIQUE_ID", "RUN_ID" 
FROM "_SYS_BIC"."xxx.dataset/PnL_Dataset"(
        PLACEHOLDER."$$jobId1$$" => 'XXXD401B-EA88-48DA-9EE6-CAE688440XXX', 
        PLACEHOLDER."$$jobId2$$" => 'XXXACBEA-5CE9-4661-AB19-654A66DD8XXX', 
        PLACEHOLDER."$$relevantJob$$" => 'XXXD401B-EA88-48DA-9EE6-CAE688440XXX') a 
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT * FROM "_SYS_BIC"."meag.app.h4q.checks/READ_JOIN_ATT_FROM_CHECK_RESULTS" 
        WHERE CHECK_ID IN ( 
            SELECT "CHECK_ID.CHECK_ID" 
            FROM     "MEAG_APP_H4Q_METADATA_001"."meag.app.h4q.metadata::DB.CHECK_TEMPLATE" 
            WHERE "DATENSEGMENT_ID.DATENSEGMENT_ID" = 7) 
                AND targetdate = ( 
                    SELECT DISTINCT a."DueDate" 
                    FROM "MEAG_EIM_TQL_001_TARGET"."TG_dbo_T_Job" a 
                        join     "MEAG_EIM_TQL_001_TARGET"."TG_dbo_T_PL_Instrument" b on b."JobId" = a."JobId" 
                    WHERE a."JobId" = '6BCD401B-EA88-48DA-9EE6-CAE688440A3C'
               ) AND ( targetjobid = 'XXXD401B-EA88-48DA-9EE6-CAE688440XXX' OR targetjobid = '') 
) b ON a."T_SCD_Instrument_RH_WPID" = b.WPID AND a."T_SCD_Instrument_RH_LegNo" = b."LegNo" 
) ;
```

Error Message is:

```
Could not execute 'insert into #my_new_table (ampel, "ReportingLevel0") SELECT CASE WHEN "CT_ERGEBNIS_UNIQUE_ID" IS ...'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [269]: too many values: ReportingLevel1: line 4 col 21 (at pos 158)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error Message is wrong / misleading.

The Problem was that the Column view Column ReportingLevel1 was defined was varchar(16).

Select from the view worked without any issue.

Also select distinct into the above table worked.

Changing the column to varchar(36) in the calculation view fixed the insert into statement